# How to search for ROS packages?

Tags: ros, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I'm just starting with ROS.
I wonder how I should search for ROS packages? Why there isn't any catalogue for packages with some topics? I mean catalogue with such topics as: SLAM, Motion control, Infrastructure, Object recognition, Image processing and so on..

I understand that this is a very basic question and so I just do not understand something basis about ROS.

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51928/how-to-search-for-ros-packages?/) by [Alexander Petrov](https://answers.ros.org/users/3939/alexander-petrov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2013-01-10

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-01-11**:
ROS is indeed lacking a lot of *portal pages*. If you know what you need you can [search in *browse software*](http://www.ros.org/browse/search.php?distro=fuerte&q=slam).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a catalog: The ROS wiki.

As to why it isn't sorted with topics: I guess because nobody did that, yet.

However, I think it might be a good idea to have overview pages, e.g. for SLAM that list all SLAM algorithms implemented as ROS packages. It's probably just a matter of starting that and people will add to that.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To know about a pkg use roslocate  pkg_name

for e.g.  roslocate info pkg_name
(note that output might contain a slightly different pkg_name ...in that case use
this name for the below steps)

to install the package

```
1] roslocate info pkg_name | rosws merge -
2] rosws update pkg_name
3] source all open terminals or simply close and open them to update $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
4] rosdep update
5] rosdep install pkg_name
6] rosmake pkg_name
```

There are more ways but this is my fav ... works for me every time !!

---

Originally posted by [codeit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3334/codeit/) with karma: 11 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rosindex tool is also very helpful for finding packages: https://index.ros.org/packages/page/1/time/

You can search for packages by name, filter by ROS distro, visualize dependencies, and quickly jump to the public repository to see the documentation there.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Duvallet](https://answers.ros.org/users/22253/felix-duvallet/) with karma: 539 on 2017-07-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [azazdeaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/35111/azazdeaz/) on 2020-07-29**:
the updated url is https://index.ros.org/packages/page/1/time/

**Comment by [Felix Duvallet](https://answers.ros.org/users/22253/felix-duvallet/) on 2020-07-29**:
Thanks @azazdeaz, I've updated the link in the answer.